# print line without the first word into a variable

Tags: bash, sed

This is my code

```
   title=""
   line=""
   fname=$1
   numoflines=$(wc -l < $fname) 
   for ((i=2 ; i<=$numoflines ; i++))
   do
   ...
   done
```

In the for loop i want to print the first word of every line into $title 
and the rest of the line without the first word into $line
(using bash)
tnx

Comment: You can have a look at the cli tool awk: http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Write-Ask-Commands-And-Scripts.htm

Comment: Can you make it clear exactly what your input looks like and what your desired outcome is? Editing the question to provide an example would help.

Comment: Writing a loop in shell is always the wrong approach for manipulating text so if that's all you're doing inside your loop (not spawning processes or moving files around or pull content off web pages, etc.) then post some sample input and expected output and we can show you the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by *print to a variable* you mean add the contents of each line to the variable. To do this, you can use the bash built-in function `read`:

```
while read -r t l; do title+="$t"; line+="$l"; done < "$fname"
```

This will add the first word of every line to `$title` and the rest of the line to `$line`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some like this:

```
echo "$fname"
This is my line.
My cat is green.
```

```
title=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$fname")
line=$(awk '{$1="";sub(/^ /,"")}1' <<< "$fname")
```

```
echo "$title"
This
My
```

```
echo "$line"
is my line.
cat is green.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using the `cut` command:

```
file="./myfile.txt"
title=$(cut -f1 -d ' ' "$file")
line=$(cut -f2- -d ' ' "$file")

#check print
pr -tm <(echo -e "TITLES\n$title") <(echo -e "LINES\n$line")
```

for the next `myfile.txt`

```
My cat is green.
Green cats are strange.
```

prints

```
TITLES                  LINES
My                      cat is green.
Green                   cats are strange.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
do
  Tempo="$( sed -n "${i} {s/^[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/title='\1';line='\2'/p;q;}" ${fname} )"
  eval "${Tempo}"
done

# or

do
  sed -n "${i} {p;q;}" | read Line Title
  # but this does not keep content available on each OS/shell
done
```

Comment: any reason why a -1 ?